Aligning space separated words in columns
There is a text file, file.txt. In there is:
abc 01245
def-1 32154
ghi-3 55432
jkl 44121
mno-4 23147
pqr 897044
....

How to format this to an output like this:
abc   01245
def-1 32154
ghi-3 55432
jkl   44121
mno-4 23147
pqr   897044
....

Can awk do this?

What have you tried?

To align columns of text, besides right-padding fields to a given length of characters¹ with awk's printf as you found, some alternatives:
You can change the space to a horizontal tabulation character and let you terminal align the text:
tr ' ' '\t' < file

By default, tab stops on terminals are generally 8 columns apart, but you can usually change that with the tabs command, or you can pipe that output to the expand command to change the TAB characters back to the right amount of space:
tr ' ' '\t' < file | expand -t10

For instance for tabulations 10 columns apart instead of 8.
If you don't know the maximum width of the columns in advance, you can also use the BSD column command:
column -t < file

It separates the columns with two spaces, but you add -o ' ' to use a single space instead.
Or, assuming all lines have exactly two fields, with BSD rs:
rs -z 0 2 < file

Again with two spaces between column but the amount of space can be changed with the -g option (rs -zg1 0 2 for instance for one space).
At least on Debian, I find that all of those still work fine if the input contains multi-byte or zero-width or double-width characters.

¹ or byte depending on the awk implementation; in any case, even with those awk implementations that support multi-byte characters, that won't work properly if the input contains zero-width or double-width characters.

The simplest way is obviously using column:
$ column -t file.txt
abc    01245
def-1  32154
ghi-3  55432
jkl    44121
mno-4  23147
pqr    897044

but if you need to use awk for some reason then here's a 2-pass approach that'll work with any awk and without reading all of the input into memory and without hard-coding a max field width:
$ cat tst.awk
NR == FNR {
    wid = length($1)
    max = ( wid > max ? wid : max )
    next
}
{ printf "%-*s %s\n", max, $1, $2 }


$ awk -f tst.awk file.txt file.txt
abc   01245
def-1 32154
ghi-3 55432
jkl   44121
mno-4 23147
pqr   897044

or a 1-pass approach (of reading the input) if the input is small enough to fit in memory and you can't use the simpler 2-pass approach above (e.g. if the input is being read from a pipe):
$ cat tst.awk
{
    wid = length($1)
    max = ( wid > max ? wid : max )
    vals[NR] = $0
}
END {
    for ( i=1; i<=NR; i++ ) {
        $0 = vals[i]
        printf "%-*s %s\n", max, $1, $2
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file.txt
abc   01245
def-1 32154
ghi-3 55432
jkl   44121
mno-4 23147
pqr   897044


Worth noting that the awk approach (contrary to the column approach) won't work properly if there are zero-width or double width characters in the first field (like in the output of printf 'Ste\u0301phane Chazelas\n' (and with some awk implementations with multi-byte characters as well regardless of their display width).

Using perl:
As suggested by @Stéphane Chazelas
$ perl -lane 'printf "%-10s %s\n", @F'

If the file has only two fields the following command may be used but this would as long as field 1 is 9 characters long.
$ perl -lane 'print($F[0], " " x (10-length($F[0])),$F[1])'


Using mlr:
$ mlr --pprint cat file | tail -n +2


... which will work as long as field #1 is 9 characters long at most, after which it will join the fields. You may not need -n if using a recent enough version of Perl (it's implied by -a in recent versions)

Or perl -lane 'printf "%-10s %s\n", @F' as perl also has printf (though that doesn't work with multi-byte, single width or double width characters either. Adding -C to your approach and replacing length with Text::CharWidth::mbswidrh would address that).

@StéphaneChazelas Could I add your command to my answer if you don't mind.

Sure, go ahead.

See also Unicode::GCString->new($string)->columns as an alternative of  Text::CharWidth::mbswidth($string) (in libunicode-linebreak-perl and libtext-charwidth-perl packages respectively on Debian-based systems)

@StéphaneChazelas Edited And Thanks.

This works in awk:
$ awk '{ printf "%-10s %s\n", $1, $2 }' file.txt
abc        01245
def-1      32154
ghi-3      55432
jkl        44121
mno-4      23147
pqr        897044

The -10s adds a padding of 10 spaces to the beginning of the first printed field, so anything that is less than ten characters long will be padded to reach ten characters.

Is this meant to be an answer to the question, or a modification of the question?  It feels like this should be edited into the question, rather than supplied as an answer

i found my answer self.

This also will work as log as field #1 is 10 characters long at most, I understand this is your question so I assume you're fine with that but it's worth pointing out for others.
